# Better explanation of unreachable code and getting value of int to another class

Tags: java

I've searched for similar posts on this matter and honestly there is a lot, but please understand that I don't. I would appreciate it if someone could explain a little better, simpler.

I am trying to write my first program. The first part of the program is to reverse the number that is entered by the user, and I don't have a problem with this. The problem is when I try to get the that reversed number into another class

Here is the code:

```
package secretIDpack;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class renNum {

int reverse = 0;
int storeNumber;

public int revMethod(){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    storeNumber = in.nextInt();

    while(storeNumber != 0) {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + storeNumber%10;
        storeNumber = storeNumber/10;
    } return reverse;

    System.out.println(reverse);
  }
}
```

The System.out.println part is just so I can confirm that the above code is working properly, which it is as long as I keep the return part out of the code. As soon as I put the return part in, I get the message that there is unreachable code at the System.out.println

Now you probably already see what is being done here, but I will make sure you understand. I need the value of the reversed number in another class where it will be worked on further like adding some value multiplying etc. So let's say the number entered is 1234 and when revMethod does its part it will be 4321, I need this number in this class

```
package secretIDpack;

public class NewSecretID {

  public static void main(String[] args){

    renNum revObject = new renNum();
    revObject.revMethod();

    System.out.println(reverse);
  }
}
```

Now in this class I get an error that "reverse" cannot be resolved to a variable, why isn't this class pulling the "reverse" value from the previous class?

Answer (score 0):

**First part of your question:**

The `return` statement will exit the method! That means that code after the return statement will not be executed and is therefore "unreachable". Just switch those two lines:

```
System.out.println(reverse);
return reverse;
```

**Second part of your question:**

The `revMethod` has a return value of `int`. To use the return value of the method you'll have to assign it to a variable in the calling method. e.g.:

```
int returnValue = revObject.revMethod();
System.out.println(returnValue);
```

Comment: @igor253 No problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

As for your first question, you have a `return` statement followed by a print statement. In this case, the problem is that when the `return` keyword is found, the execution flow will exit that method. Thus, anything which follows will never executed.

To fix this, you would simply need to invert the order of your `return` and `print` statement such that the printing will take place before returning.

As per your second question, the `reverse` string does not exist within your `main` method. It exists in some other method which you are calling, but it is never declared in your `NewSecretID` class, which is why you are getting that error.

Variables declared within methods are not available outside the declaring method. Same applies for class lever variables, since they are not available outside that class. Just to be clear, you can access them, just not in the way you are doing it.

To solve your second issue, just do `int reverse = revObject.revMethod()`. This would place whatever it is that `revMethod` gives back into an integer variable called `reverse`. For the sake of completeness you can rename `reverse` to anything you like. `int foo = revObject.revMethod()` would also work.

Comment: Ah perfect, solved in 2 minutes. Thank you very much for your help!